# Don't allow specific letters in ALL textbox for MS Access

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, user-input

On a form, i have 13 `textbox`. When user click on save button, Access calls an API and passes the values in these text boxes to the API (via HTTP REST)

There are some characters which are not allowed like `"` not allowed to be saved through API. Hence I want to restrict users from Entering these Characters.

Currently I have created a `Public` `Function` which is called from `KeyPress` Event to check if the Characters are allowed or Not. But I have to call this function from every `textbox`  `KeyPress` event. *Is there a way to not allow `"` across all the text boxes??*

**Function**

```
Public Function CharsNotAllowed(myChar As Integer) As Integer

    If myChar = 34 Then
        Beep 'Let the user know they hit an illegal key
        CharsNotAllowed = 0 'Don't let the keystroke through
    Else
        CharsNotAllowed = myChar
    End If

End Function
```

**Function Calling**

```
Private Sub StudentName_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    KeyAscii = CharsNotAllowed(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Sub StudentClass_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    KeyAscii = CharsNotAllowed(KeyAscii)
End Sub

'and so on for all the 13 text boxes
```

*Note* : `34` represents `"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried on `Form` level? BTW, most of the time users copy and paste, this will allow users to enter those unwanted characters (just a reminder :))

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   If ActiveControl.ControlType = 109 Then 'only for textboxes
       KeyAscii = CharsNotAllowed(KeyAscii)
   End If
End Sub
```